# Hartree-Fock Method, one-electron operator, dummy variable coordinates of electron one

Tags: quantum-mechanics

In Hartree-Fock method, one is interested in calculating the energy expectation value for a Slater determinant. The problem is separated into an one-electron operator and a two-electron operator.
For a system with two electrons we can write down the one-electron operator $\hat{O}_1 = \hat{h}(1) + \hat{h}(2)$. Where $\hat{h}(1)$ is a core Hamiltonian for electron one, describing it's kinetic energy and potential energy in the field of the nuclei and $\hat{h}(2)$ is a core Hamiltonian for electron two, describing it's kinetic energy and potential energy in the field of the nuclei.
For $<\Psi^{SD}(1,2)|\hat{h(1)}|\Psi^{SD}(1,2)>$ we can write down ($\chi_1(1)$, $\chi_2(1)$, $\chi_1(2)$ and $\chi_2(2)$ are spin orbitals):
\begin{equation}
      <\Psi^{SD}(1,2)|\hat{h}(1)|\Psi^{SD}(1,2)> = \frac{1}{2} \left[ <\chi_1(1)|\hat{h}(1)|\chi_1(1)> +  <\chi_2(1)|\hat{h}(1)|\chi_2(1)>\right]
\end{equation}
For $<\Psi^{SD}(1,2)|\hat{h}(2)|\Psi^{SD}(1,2)>$:
\begin{equation}
      <\Psi^{SD}(1,2)|\hat{h}(2)|\Psi^{SD}(1,2)> = \frac{1}{2} \left[ <\chi_1(2)|\hat{h}(2)|\chi_1(2)> +  <\chi_2(2)|\hat{h}(2)|\chi_2(2)>\right]
\end{equation}

Now the question: Why we are able to say, that $<\Psi^{SD}(1,2)|\hat{h}(1)|\Psi^{SD}(1,2)> = <\Psi^{SD}(1,2)|\hat{h}(2)|\Psi^{SD}(1,2)>$? I guess we can do this, because electrons are undistinguishable, but I am not sure, if there is another reason.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, one have to understand first that the very phrase "core Hamiltonian for electron one" (or electron two, if it matters) sounds a bit odd. The core Hamiltonian be definition describes a one-electron system in which there only single electron. In principle one is free to call this single electron electron-one or electron-two or use any other name for it, but it simply one and only electron in the one-electron system described by the core Hamiltonian. In fact, the usual meaning of the symbol (1) the core Hamiltonian operator is to simply indicate that this operator is a one-electron in nature, thus writing (2) after the core Hamiltonian is not quite right from that perspective.

Another way to look at all this business it to think about this symbol (1) as an indication that the core Hamiltonian operator is written in terms of coordinates of electron-one and is acting on functions of coordinates of electron-one. In such a case one have to remember that this electron-one is still the only electron in the one-electron system under consideration. And that this is just a rather useful convention to call this only electron electron-one, but in principle you can call this only electron electron-two. This would be a bit odd, but there is nothing wrong with that. From that point of view the two expressions in question are obviously equal to each other (or should we even say equivalent), since it is indeed the matter of simply relabelling the one and only electron from electron-one to electron-two.

Comment: thank you very much!